# Are there statistics about bounties?

Tags: discussion, bounties, data-dump, statistics, data-analysis

I would like to see some statistics on bounty awards. More specifically, things like:

- How often are different bounty-levels rewarded?
- Has anyone got a bounty of more than 500?

Comment: 550 is the highest a bounty can be.  See [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Ah, I misunderstood it. I thought that SO add the same amount of rep as the user did. But as you pointed out, SO always add 50 rep to the bounty. I updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how the data dump schema will be changing (if at all) given the recent changes to the bounty system, but in the meantime, I created a [Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/) query that shows the number of bounties awarded for each bounty level. You can find the query [here](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/262/bounty-award-counts).

I'll update it if necessary after the next data dump.

**EDIT:** Oops! I should have checked more carefully. When the bounty amount is zero, that means a user self-accepted a bounty. When the bounty amount is `NULL`, that meant the bounty expired. I've updated the query to show these properly now.

Comment: Very cool query! It's a shame it can't differentiate assigned and half bounties for 50/100/150/200/250, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, that information is not available in the data dump. I have a post written up about how to fix it, but I'm waiting to see the changes to the database schema first, since that's only a week or so away. Looking at the results of the query, those numbers do stick out somewhat, probably because of auto-acceptance. @Gra

Comment: Does anyone know what the '0' bounties are?

Comment: @Margaret: I made a mistake in my last comment. I've updated both my answer and the query.